# Why the OS is changing the assigned outgoing port of my packets?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, tcp, port

My C++ software is creating syn packets (using boost) to my server with specific outgoing ports (according to the IANA port-assignment standards).
I am picking the outgoing ports for internal purposes.

For some reason, after I checked my application on many machines, with one specific machine am having the below issue:

The outgoing port which is being used isn't the one I assigned - Looks like the OS (Windows 10) is changing it.

What can be the issue?

Below is the relevant code I am using for assigning specific outgoing port:

```
std::string exceptionFormat = "exception. Error message: ";
error_code socket_set_option_error_code;
socket->set_option(tcp::socket::reuse_address(true), socket_set_option_error_code);
if (socket_set_option_error_code) {
    throw SocketException("Got socket reuse set option " + exceptionFormat + socket_set_option_error_code.message());
}
const auto source_endpoint = tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), source_port);
error_code bind_socket_error_code;
socket->bind(source_endpoint, bind_socket_error_code);
if (bind_socket_error_code) {
    throw SocketException("Got socket bind " + exceptionFormat + bind_socket_error_code.message());
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the received data appears to have a source port other than that defined by `source_port`?  If so, it sounds as if the connection might just be going through one or more [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) layers.

Comment: The OS can't change the source port once it is bound. Something else is going on. Maybe on that 1 machine, the connection is passing through a proxy/router and you are seeing the proxy/router's source port rather than your client's source port. Or maybe you are simply looking at the wrong socket/connection. Hard to say for sure since you didn't say where exactly you are seeing the wrong outgoing port

Comment: I am seeing the wrong outgoing port on the server and on the client (by printing the netstat data when the connection is created).

Comment: From my logs:   
Establish a connection to 192.168.12.1: 21 with source port: 49297
From netstats (on the client):
TCP    192.168.13.11:52352   192.168.12.1:21     TIME_WAIT       0

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there were 2 antivirus installed on the machine while one of them changed the outgoing port (Kaspersky).

Answer (score 0):

Tha packets might be flowing through NAT module (NAPT) or firewall which could also be one main reason due to which the port numbers can change.